How to make a read-only Jupyter Notebook file writable in PyCharm?
I am struggling to edit a jupyter notebook file in pycharm. When the 'clear read-only status' dialouge box appears, I try to make it writable by using the file system option, but in vain. I am also facing problems in running the notebook directly in Jupyter Notebook as it fails to recognise the installed packages like numpy and pandas.

"I am also facing problems in ..."  Ideally one specific problem per post. Granted your post is short but you've essentially thrown in at the last sentence something else unrelated.  About, " in Jupyter Notebook as it fails to recognise the installed packages like numpy and pandas": it is likely you are confusing 'installed' with the more important 'installed in the correct place where the kernel can see it'. Usually things need special handling so you insure that a Jupyter ipykernel kernel is connected to the environment where installs done outside of that running kernel were performed. ...

 Are you just using pip for installs or does your current situation involve Anaconda/conda? (This would be important to include in a related post about this last sentence you threw in here. Or probably more pertinent here since this is well-travelled ground on StackOverflow and related places, use such related information among the appropriate terms as you seek help among the many posts already covering such issues.) Using the appropriate magic install command inside your running notebook before you do any import, can help you get past this hurdle without endeavoring right now ...

 to learn the proper way to link things installed to the kernel's environment. See more about the modern %pip install command  (or modern %conda install command, if you are using Anaconda/conda) here. Running for example, %pip install pandas numpy in the cell at the top of your notebook might solve all your problems with using Jupyter Notebook and then you might not need PyCharm. (See about the XY problem is it is somewhat related.)

Hi, I am using Anaconda for package installations and thank you very much for your help. Appreciate it.

Then the command using the magic install would be %conda install conda-forge::pandas, based on here and %conda install conda-forge::numpy, based on here. (Or just, I believe: %conda install conda-forge::pandas conda-forge::numpy -y as one command that will run without additional questions. I think.) See the top two scoring answers here for the proper options to do it with the install not from inside the running notebook.
